# Sum grouped by multiple columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, pivot

I have the following table

```
color       shape         material       value    qt
----------------------------------------------------
green       cylinder      plastic         12       2
white       cube          wood            5        1
green       cylinder      plastic         6        2
white       cube          wood            5        2
green       cylinder      plastic         2        2
```

I want to have the sum of values that have the same criteria. I want something like the following.

```
color       shape         material       sum
-----------------------------------------------
green       cylinder      plastic        28
white       cube          wood           15
green       cylinder      plastic        12
```

I have a lot of colors, shapes and materials so I would like a dynamic query. I don't know where to start.

EDIT

There is other characteristics that makes every record different

Comment: how did you compute those values?

Comment: difference between green cylinder the first and the third?

Comment: Yes because they have other characteristic that are not displayed here

Comment: Well, you better display them here, since they seem to be important to find the correct solution.

Comment: How can we help you if you don't display all the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select color, shape, material, sum( value * qt )
from tbl
group by color, shape, material
```

Answer (score 1):

If it as simple as your description makes it sounds

```
SELECT color, shape, material, SUM(value)
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY color, shape, material
```

But not sure your example output table ties up with your description and original data